# Revalidation is working only once when I use generateStaticParams

Tags: express, next.js, interrupt, next.js13

I tried to implement ISR in my app but the revalidation works only once and not update the page after the revalidate time. And sometimes the page becomes unreachable and Links are not working.

This is my code
path - src/app/games/page.tsx

```
import GamesHeroSection from "@/components/GamesPage/Sections/GamesHeroSection";
import GamesNewsletter from "@/components/GamesPage/Sections/GamesNewsletter";
import GamesQuotMessage from "@/components/GamesPage/Sections/GamesQuotMessage";
import GamesShowcaseSection from "@/components/GamesPage/Sections/GamesShowcaseSection";
import GamesUpdateSection from "@/components/GamesPage/Sections/GamesUpdateSection";
import GamesServicesSection from "@/components/GamesPage/Sections/GamesServicesSection";
import { GameList } from "@/types/Games";
import { baseUrl } from "@/lib/apiUrl";

type Props = {};

async function getGames() {
  const result = await fetch(baseUrl+"/games",{next:{revalidate:60}});
  return result.json();
}

const GamesPage = async(props: Props) => {
  const data : GameList[] = await getGames(); // only uncomment when backend is connected

  return (
    <div id="GamesPage"className="select-none" >
      <GamesHeroSection />
      <GamesQuotMessage />
      <GamesServicesSection />
      <GamesShowcaseSection gameList={data} />
      <GamesUpdateSection />
      <GamesNewsletter />
    </div>
  );
};

export default GamesPage;
```

Second Page

path - src/app/games/[id]/page.tsx

```
import GameViewAboutSection from "@/components/GamesPageView/Sections/GameViewAboutSection";
import GameViewHeroSection from "@/components/GamesPageView/Sections/GameViewHeroSection";
import GameViewScreenshotSection from "@/components/GamesPageView/Sections/GameViewScreenshotSection";
import FaqBox from "@/components/utils/FaqBox";
import { baseUrl } from "@/lib/apiUrl";
import { GameList } from "@/types/Games";

type Props = {};

export async function generateStaticParams() {
  const games = await fetch(baseUrl+"/games", {
    next: { revalidate: 60 },
  }).then((res) => res.json());
  return games.map((game: GameList) => ({
    id: game._id,
  }));
}

async function getGameById(id:string) {
  const result = await fetch(baseUrl+`/games/${id}`,{method:"GET",cache:'no-store'})
  return result.json()
}

const GamesViewPage = async ({ params }: { params: { id: string } }) => {
  const data: GameList = await getGameById(params.id);
  return (
    <div id="GamesViewPage" className="select-none">
      <GameViewHeroSection data={data} />
      <GameViewScreenshotSection data={data} />
      <GameViewAboutSection data={data} />
      <FaqBox data={data.faq} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default GamesViewPage;
import GameViewAboutSection from "@/components/GamesPageView/Sections/GameViewAboutSection";
import GameViewHeroSection from "@/components/GamesPageView/Sections/GameViewHeroSection";
import GameViewScreenshotSection from "@/components/GamesPageView/Sections/GameViewScreenshotSection";
import FaqBox from "@/components/utils/FaqBox";
import { baseUrl } from "@/lib/apiUrl";
import { GameList } from "@/types/Games";

type Props = {};

export async function generateStaticParams() {
  const games = await fetch(baseUrl+"/games", {
    next: { revalidate: 60 },
  }).then((res) => res.json());
  return games.map((game: GameList) => ({
    id: game._id,
  }));
}

async function getGameById(id:string) {
  const result = await fetch(baseUrl+`/games/${id}`,{method:"GET",cache:'no-store'})
  return result.json()
}

const GamesViewPage = async ({ params }: { params: { id: string } }) => {
  const data: GameList = await getGameById(params.id);
  return (
    <div id="GamesViewPage" className="select-none">
      <GameViewHeroSection data={data} />
      <GameViewScreenshotSection data={data} />
      <GameViewAboutSection data={data} />
      <FaqBox data={data.faq} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default GamesViewPage;
```

Need help to fix this issue backend is a express app

I Tried to revalidate the both the gamespage and it's dynamic routes [id]/page.tsx every 60 sec but it only happens once and not working after that.